# How to make child scrollable when parent has no more space to grow

Tags: html, css

[image]

Here is my attempt:
http://jsbin.com/xokidev/7/edit?html,output

```
  <phone style="
    display:block;
    position:relative; 
    margin:auto; 
    width:300px; 
    height:500px;
    background:silver;
    overflow:hidden">
    <navigation-or-something style="
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      height:100px; 
      width:100%;
      background:skyblue">
      known height. don't overlap
    </navigation-or-something>
    <component style="
      position: absolute; 
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0; 
      max-height: calc(100% - 100px); 
      display:block;">
      <header style="background:yellow">
        multiline variable text height. multiline variable text height
      </header>
      <container style="
        display:block; 
        background: pink; 
        overflow-y:auto;">
        <content>
          some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. 
        </content>
      </container>
    </component>
  </phone>
```

The problem you'll find is that my pink child doesn't start scrolling once the parent has no more space to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column;` to make it scroll only pink part

```html
<phone style="
    display:block;
    position:relative; 
    margin:auto; 
    width:300px; 
    height:500px;
    background:silver;
    overflow:hidden">
  <navigation-or-something style="
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      height:100px; 
      width:100%;
      background:skyblue">
    known height. don't overlap
  </navigation-or-something>
  <component style="
      position: absolute; 
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0; 
      max-height: calc(100% - 100px); 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;">
    <header style="background:yellow">
      multiline variable text height. multiline variable text height
    </header>
    <container style="
        display:block; 
        background: pink;
        overflow-y:auto;">
      <content>
        some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable
        height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height
        content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content.
        some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some
        variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content.
      </content>
    </container>
  </component>
</phone>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using flex sealed the deal:

http://jsbin.com/xokidev/8/edit?html,output

```
  <phone style="
    display:block;
    position:relative; 
    margin:auto; 
    width:300px; 
    height:500px;
    background:silver;
    overflow:hidden">
    <navigation-or-something style="
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      height:100px; 
      width:100%;
      background:skyblue">
      known height. don't overlap
    </navigation-or-something>
    <component style="
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute; 
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0; 
      max-height: calc(100% - 100px);">
      <header style="background:yellow">
        multiline variable text height. multiline variable text height
      </header>
      <container style="
        display:block; 
        background: pink; 
        overflow: auto;">
        <content>
          some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. some variable height content. 
        </content>
      </container>
    </component>
  </phone>
```